# set anchor tags for particular tab in a section of webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

As this is a simple question I guess its not needed to paste the entire code.

I have set anchor tags in navigation section in the left to take me to different sections in my site like `home, about, contact`, etc.
In the contact section I have three tabs like `location, address, contact` in the same order.

So when ever I click the contact in the navigation menu it should take me to the location tab in the contact section. That is actually done. But its doing this only at page reload.
When I click on the address tab in the contact section, go back to home and then if I again click on contact menu in navigation list its displaying me the contents of address and not the location. I need the contact menu to take me to the location tab of the contact section every time and not only at page reload.

http://s133036305.onlinehome.us/#home

Navigation Menu(side bar):

```
<div id="navigation" class="span3">
    <div class="tabbable tabs-left">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" style "width: 220px;">
            <li class="active"><a href="#home" data-toggle="tab"> Home </a></li>
            <li><a href="#about" data-toggle="tab"> About Us </a></li>
            <li><a href="#service" data-toggle="tab"> Services </a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact" data-toggle="tab"> Contact </a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="tab-content">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Contact Section:

```
<div class="tabbable">
    <!-- Only required for left/right tabs -->
    <ul id="contact" class="nav-tabs">
        <li class="active"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">
        <h2>Address</h2>
        </a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">
        <h2>Location</h2>
        </a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab">
        <h2>Contact</h2>
        </a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
            <ul style "list-style-type:none; height:500px;">
                <li> Corporate Building </li>
                <a href "www.leadgp.org" target="_blank">
                <li> www.leadgp.org </li>
                </a>
                <li> No.143, </li>
                <li> Dr.Jaganathan Nagar, </li>
                <li> 1st Street, </li>
                <li> Civil Aerodrome Post, </li>
                <li> Coimbatore-641014. </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
            <div class "map" p">
                <div id="map" style="width: 760px; height: 500px; background: url(http://geofinder.web4you.com.pl/template/loader.gif); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center;">
                </div>
                <div style="padding-top:10px; text-align: right; width: 790px;">
                </div>
            </div>
            <br>
            <br>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="tab3">
            <form method="get" action="MAILTO:mail@Datacrawl.org" method="post" enctype="text/plain" id="contact-form" class="form-horizontal form1" style "height: t: 500px; <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="name"> Name* </label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input style "height: t: 30px;" type="text" class="span3" name="name" id="name">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="email"> Email </label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="text" class="span3" name="email" id="email">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="address">Address</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <textarea class="span3 required" name="address" id="address" rows="3"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="number"> Phone </label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input style "height: t: 30px;" type="text" class "span3" 3" name "number" r" id "number" r">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="comments"> Message </label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <textarea class "span3" 3" name "comments" s" id "comments" s" rows "3" 3"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-actions">
                <button type="submit" class="submit btn btn-primary" style "font-family: 'droid sans', sans-serif;">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: On a general note: The reason why posting the **relevant** code (not entire), even for a simple question, is a good thing is that most of the time what people **think and say** they have done is different to what they **actually** have done. And usualy that is why code doesn't work as expected. In addition linking to your code is not usefull to any other user in the future with simlar issues ones the link is dead, making this question redundant thereafter. Please post the relvant code to not having to rely on a link alone to make this question usefull and clear.

Comment: In **addition** to posting the relvant code you could look into creating a fiddle on http://jsFiddle.net demonstrating the issue, if possible that is. That always helps.

Comment: Sorry. I posted the code. Will try with that fiddle thing.

Comment: It will work at first load. But after that it will only take to the current tab selected in contact section and not particularly location tab.

Answer (score 0):

Where do your (anchor)links link to? Normally you would have the link that is actually used to be clicked on, for example:

Go to location

And you would have your anchorlink to which the page will go after clicking, like so:

```
<a name="location"></a>
```

Comment: <li><a href="#contact" data-toggle="tab"> Contact </a></li> .This is linked to the <ul id="contact" class="nav-tabs">. So when I click on the contact link it takes me to the <ul>. But in that ul I have three tabs. I need the link to take me to a particular tab location in <ul> every time I click on contact link.

Comment: This is working in the first load as "location"<ul> tab in contact section is first tab. But I need it every time I click on contact link<a>. Guess u got it. Im ready to explain further if you dont.:)

Answer (score 0):

To clarify, what you want is to link the 'Contact' link from your menu to a particular tab in your contact section?

So if you have 'Hello' selected and you click the contact link again, it will reset to the default tab?

If so, you could use javascript/jQuery to click on the default Tab everytime the contact us link is pressed. Something like this:

```
$('#ContactLinkID').click(function(){
$('#DefaultTabID').click();
});
```